# how does a router advertise itself and the hotspot?

Tags: router, ipv6, scapy, icmp, ads

In which protocol does router use to advertise itself and the network(including the name of the netwrok, like hotspot)?
I haven't found it on the interent, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Routers don't do that. Routers can advertise network prefixes though a routing protocol, if one is configured on the router, but that is all they advertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to Wireless APs, they advertise themselves using the IEEE 802.11 standard. Particularly, beacon frames are used. You can check these frames on Wireshark captures: https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#Wifi_.2F_Wireless_LAN_captures_.2F_802.11

On the other hand, if you mean over the wire, as you have been already told, they do not advertise their name. In IPv6 there is the [NDP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) which advertises routers, but not their names. However, you can use reverse DNS query to obtain the DNS name of a router, so maybe you refer to that.